# Exibir apenas um registro com o foreach

Tags: php, mysql, foreach

Preciso de ajuda para exibir apenas um registro do banco de dados, segue código:

```
<?php
    $posts  = DBRead( 'posts', "WHERE categoria = 3 AND status = 1 ORDER BY data_numero ASC" );

    if( !$posts )
        echo '<h2>Nenhuma Corrida Registrada!</h2>';
    else
        foreach ( $posts as $post ):
?>
```

Precisaria fazer o foreach retornar o com a data menor e somente um para inserir numa BOX.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode limitar sua *query* para um único resultado, assim o `foreach` terá só uma iteração.

```
<?php
    $posts  = DBRead( 'posts', "WHERE categoria = 3 AND status = 1 ORDER BY data_numero ASC LIMIT 1" );

    if( !$posts )
        echo '<h2>Nenhuma Corrida Registrada!</h2>';
    else
        foreach ( $posts as $post ):
?>
```

Ou então logo em seguida no seu código dar um `break`

```
<?php
    $posts  = DBRead( 'posts', "WHERE categoria = 3 AND status = 1 ORDER BY data_numero ASC" );

    if( !$posts )
        echo '<h2>Nenhuma Corrida Registrada!</h2>';
    else
        foreach ( $posts as $post ):
?>
Dados do post: <?=$post?>
<?php break; ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: Deu certo aqui, mas queria saber também se daria para fazer excluir automaticamente uma entrada no PHP depois que a data passar.

Comment: @MateusJoséPretti pode ser mais claro?

Comment: Posso Sim, assim olha.
Depois de que a data registrada no banco de dados for passada pela data atual, o sistema ia excluir a linha que tem a data ultrapassada. exemplo:
Linha no DB: data: 11/01/2017 Dia Atual: 15/01/2017
A database deveria apagar os dados com a data inferior da data atual no GMT-1 = 14/01/2017, se não entendeu pergunta dnv kkkkk

Answer (score 4):

Se quer um só não precisa de `foreach`, basta pegar pelo índice:

```
<?php
    $posts = DBRead('posts', "WHERE categoria = 3 AND status = 1 ORDER BY data_numero ASC");

    if( !$posts ) {
        echo '<h2>Nenhuma Corrida Registrada!</h2>';
    } else {
        $post = $posts[0]; // Pega o primeiro, sem precisar de foreach
    }
?>
```

O `foreach` itera a variável desde `$posts[0]` até `$posts[ultimo item]`, no sei caso se quer um só, especifica o primeiro índice, que é zero.

Se forem muitos ítens retornados originalmente, pode limitar a busca com um `LIMIT 1` no final da *query* como comentado pelo @gmsantos. Isto não vai afetar a saída na tela com a solução atual, mas vai economizar a transmissão desnecessária de dados.

Comment: Ta certo a sua valeu, tenho outra pergunta da uma olhada no comentário da resposta ai em baixo.